# Calling VB.Net function from c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, compiler-errors

I've a vb.net class library and my c# application is accessing that method.  My C# code gives me compile time error that 'Start' is not supported by language, where Start is my method name.

Signature of Start method is

```
Public Sub Start(Byval frm as Form,
                 ByVal db as DBAccess,
                 ByVal roleID as integer)
```

where DBAccess is a userDefined class

and my c# calling code is

```
obj.Start(frm, db, roleID);
```

Thanks

Comment: I doubt that the error message is that "'Start' is not supported by language". Please show more of your calling code, including the declaration of `obj`, and the *exact* compilation error.

Comment: Public static Accessor obj=new Accessor;  Do you think static keyword has anything to do with that? My class is static where i wrote this code. And compile time error is exactly what i've told earlier.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5840b5d(v=vs.80).aspx explains the error message (edit: that's for classes, not method names), no clue what causes it in your case, though.

Comment: @Jon Skeet This error occurs because of some incompatible things between VB.NET and C#. This can happen with exactly this error text.

Comment: @MSingh: That's not your exact C# code, and I doubt that the error is *exactly* what you wrote either (given the grammatical problems of "not supported by language"). Cut and paste is your friend here.

Comment: @VMAtm: Exactly this error text including "not supported by language" rather than "not supported by *the* language"? That's what made me suspicious...

Comment: @Jon Skeet Well, you are right. My bad, my english not good to notice such things. But it seems problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mswinswdev/ms_csharp_proprety_indexer_or_event_not_supported_by_the_language.htm), this error can be caused by optional parameters in VB.net declaration or not-supported types in C#.
May be you should just recompile your vb.net library and re-add reference to your c# project.
But I think you should change your method definition to such:

```
Public Sub Start(Byval frm as Form, ByVal db as DBAccess, ByVal roleID as Int32)
```

type of roleID is changed from [`Integer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bkb8w2.aspx) to [`Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx).